# Approximation of piecewise linear functions by constant function

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, approximation, spline

Let $f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
A_1 x + B_1 &\mbox{if } x \in [a, x_0] \\
A_2 x + B_2 & \mbox{if } x \in [x_0, b]
\end{cases}$ and $f \in C[a, b]$ i.e. f has the "angle" form.

Denote $E_t(f) = ||f(x) - t||_{L_p[a,b]} = (\int_a^b |f(x) - t|^p dx)^{1/p}$.

What is $\inf_{t \in \mathbb{R}} E_t(f)$?

In other words, which of the constants $t$ best approximates the function in the $L_p$ metric?

I can't find the exact value, so it would be great to know if there are any good estimates for this value.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to take any $t$ and compute the integral ?

Comment: Why do you say that $f$ has the "angle form"? Are there any restrictions on the constants that you are not reporting?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. There are too many cases depending on the choice of A1 and A2. Moreover, E_t(f) has the form in which it is difficult to minimize it for an arbitrary q. I would like to have some estimate for this value.

Comment: And yes, there is restriction $f(x) \in C[a,b]$, i.e. B2 can be expressed in terms of A1, A2, B1.